# Checking for recent file edits with bash, and executing time-based logic

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use bash to check if a specific file was edited within the past 30 minutes.  If so, it terminates. If not, I want to use that same bash script to send an email. This script will then be triggered by a cron job.

I am checking the metadata for last edit using `stat -c %y file.txt` which outputs the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000000000 -0400`

The email part is easy too, since I can just use `mail` to send that out.

What I'm lacking is the important part...the conditional logic. I can grab the current time with something like `date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"` which results in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` but that has fewer significant digits than the metadata timestamp. I assume this means I need to trim off the last 16 digits from the metadata stamp, but do not know how to do that. The largest problem in my mind, though, is that I need a way to compare these. While I could try to do simple arithmetic during most of the day (using if -lt most likely), we all know that quickly falls apart when dealing with clocks.  How can I process this timestamp as a time, rather than just a number?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` with the `-mmin` to test if the file has been modified less than 30 minutes ago. If the file fits the criteria, the filename will be output, otherwise the output will be empty.

```
result=$(find file.txt -mmin -30)
if [ -z "$result" ]
then
    mail ...
fi
```

Comment: Ok, I had to use an "else" because the logic was backwards, but other than that (and I typo I added), this works great. Thank you!

Comment: You can use `+30` to invert the time test, or use `-z "$result"` to test if the result is empty.

Comment: I misread what action you wanted to take in each case.

Answer (score 0):

Decide if you want **human**-readable or computer parsable format. `%y` is for humans, use `%Y` for machines.

You would use and compare `stat -c %.Y` output with `date +%s.%N` (using `bc` or `awk` - research how to compare floating point numbers on this forum). Then, *if* you need human redable format, you would convert seconds since epoch to date with `date -d "@<number>"`.

Comment: Good point. Epoch would probably save me some headaches. I think for simplicity I'm going to use Barmar's suggestion, but thank you very much for the input!